# How does document set permissions to files under it? - SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-set

How does the Doc Set permissions work.I have created a some document sets which i have assigned unique users to and then added some files under the document set. I taught with this approach users would only see there folder in the document set as i have locked the document set/folder with unique permissions but it seems users cant see the files under the document sets and no access to files.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

There is a great video by RackSpace on Document Sets, and how they're used.
The clear difference is that with a Document Set, you can create a workflow around the Document Set and you can have separate workflows against the documents within the Document Set.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV2h3z4mLC0

Comment: just a note: be sure that documents are checked in for this will keep people from seeing the documents even though they have permission.

Comment: The docs are all checked in. Is it possible to have a workflow on a document set  that would  run to assign read permissions to all files in a document set?

Comment: Any suggestions from anyone?